# inputenc, active catcode and \csnsame

Tags: macros, input-encodings, catcodes

with this MWE, with a non utf-8 engine (like pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname a\endcsname{toto}


\expandafter\def\csname ᾧ\endcsname{toto}

\end{document}
```

`\expandafter\def\csname a\endcsname{toto}` works, `\expandafter\def\csname ᾧ\endcsname{toto}` fails. I suppose because ᾧ should contains bytes made active.

My question is:is it possible to let ᾧ be read without any active character, but like a series of 1 byte character?

If there is no solution, it's ok. But I was just asking, because maybe some TeX guru could help me.

If there is one solution, is possible `ᾧ` as argument of a macro like:

```
\def\bar#1{
  #1%Here #1 should use active code inside
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{toto}%Here, it should not.
} 
\bar{ᾧ}
```

Comment: Can we use e-TeX? It's trivial if we can.

Comment: yes we can ! (nothing to do with Obama, anywhere)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all we are worried about is potentially active tokens, e-TeX's `\detokenize` will sort things out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname a\endcsname{toto}

\expandafter\def\csname \detokenize{ᾧ}\endcsname{toto}
\expandafter\show\csname \detokenize{ᾧ}\endcsname
\end{document}
```

This applies to all of the bytes of the awkward multi-byte sequence here so does the job nicely. Without e-TeX we can achieve the detokenization using `\meaning` or the LaTeX wrapper `\@onelevel@santize`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\def\csname a\endcsname{toto}

\makeatletter
\def\@tempa{ᾧ}
\@onelevel@sanitize\@tempa
\expandafter\def\csname \@tempa\endcsname{toto}
\expandafter\show\csname \@tempa\endcsname
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

(Note that XeTeX has or at least has had issues with `\detokenize` and non-BMP chars. Since we are using an 8-bit engine here we should be fine.)

Comment: and so, with command inside

Comment: ````\def\tutu#1{
\expandafter\def\csname \detokenize{#1}\endcsname{toto}
}````

Comment: it seems to work. Now, I have to 1) try in reality 2) make exception when using XeTeX

Comment: @Maïeul You'll be _very_ unlucky to run into the XeTeX bug: it's only seen with non-BMP chars

Comment: ok. But one more test is better than an imprevious bug. I don't see why eledmac users would use non-BMP chars, but it still surprising. And as I don't need \detokinize with XeTeX.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the use of this would be. But you can stringify the UTF-8 sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\utfcsdef}[1]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\stringify#1\endcsname
}

\def\stringify#1{%
  \ifx#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \string#1%
    \expandafter\stringify
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\utfcsuse}[1]{%
  \csname\stringify#1\endcsname
}

\utfcsdef{ᾧ}{toto}

\begin{document}

\utfcsuse{ᾧ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the use is for a feature of eledmac, \sameword.

Comment: see https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/301. The solution of Joseph Wright some to be simpler. I will test it.

Comment: @Maïeul Notably, this is expandable without e-TeX: my approach isn't.

Comment: @JosephWright yes, but as eledmac need e-TeX in any case....